# What are the different provinces mentioned in a Game of Thrones?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire, game-of-thrones

At one point in *Game of Thrones*, it says that no longer are there Seven Kingdoms, since they have been united, but now there are provinces:

> That was close on three hundred years ago, when the Seven Kingdoms *were* kingdoms, not mere provinces of a greater realm.

What are the names of these provinces, and which houses control them?

Comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/28004/in-game-of-thrones-which-were-the-seven-kingdoms-of-westeros - Possible duplicate. That question lists them as kingdoms instead of provinces, but I believe the names stay the same.

Comment: @fire.eagle No, I'm specifically asking about the provinces that were formed after the unification of the Seven Kingdoms. They are two separate things (although they may overlap in parts).

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt Actually, I think they are exactly the same. The kings of the old kingdoms became lords, but the areas are the same, except that the riverlands and iron islands became separate. It is interesting that the crownlands seemed to be independent before the conquest. Wonder if that ties in to the story told to Brienne by Dick Crabb.

Comment: @TLP There's overlap, but I wanted to be sure, and as you point out, the answers are actually different. I don't know what to make of the Crownlands, and who may have controlled that area (if indeed it was seen as separate then). Perhaps a good question to post? :)

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt Could be. I can't recall anything being said about it in the books, except what Dick Crabb mentioned.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It really depends on how you define provinces. But it is mostly agreed that Westeros is divided into these large chunks. Note: this is the political situation at the beginning of Game of Thrones only.

[image: Westeros Political Map]

1. **The North**. Which pretty much includes everything north of the Neck and south of the Wall. It is ruled by House Stark from their seat at Winterfell.
2. **The Riverlands**. South of the Neck and encompassing the fertile area containing much of Westeros's rivers (hence the name). It is ruled by House Tully from their seat at Riverrun.
3. **The Westerlands**. The area to the west of Westeros. It is ruled by House Lannister from their seat at Casterly Rock.
4. **The Iron Islands**. Seven large islands to the north west of Westeros.. They are ruled by House Grayjoy from their seat at Pyke.
5. **The Vale of Arryn**. A mountainous area to the east of Westeros. It is ruled by House Arryn from their seat at The Eyrie.
6. **The Crownlands**. The area surrounding the capital, King's Landing. It is directly ruled by the Crown (at the time King Robert Baratheon, first of his name ... etc etc.)
7. **The Reach**. Fertile area to the south west of Westeros. It is ruled by House Tyrell from their seat at Highgarden.
8. **Dorne**. Arrid area to the south east of Westeros. It is ruled by House Martell from their seat at Sunspear.
9. **The Stormlands**. Coastal area between Dorne and the Crownlands. It is ruled by House Baratheon from their seat at Storm's End.

Each of these lands and their respective Great Houses rule over a large number of feudal lords who have their own lands within the greater province.

Comment: That political map probably isn't from the beginning of Game of Thrones, as it gives the Crownlands to House Targaryen :) Thanks, though!

Comment: At the beginning of Game of Thrones the map is the same, but Targaryen zone is "Crown zone", so it's also Baratheon, but only while their house keeps as kings.

Comment: I think the Crownlands were originally House Targaryen's lands and Westeros's seat of power (King's Landing) was built within House Targaryen's lands because they were the King's of Westeros up until Robert Baratheon took the throne.

Comment: @jaybird93 - That's true. When the Targaryens fled Valyria after the Doom they colonized Dragonstone. When Aegon I started his conquest he built the city of King's Landing on the site where his forces first landed, and made it his capitol. As such, the surrounding lands became property of the Crown.

Comment: But these are 9, not 7 kingdoms. So which are the 7 kingdoms that are constantly referred to? Also, I'm surprised to find the Iron Islands to the west. The opening sequence of the TV show made me believe they're to the east, and looked more like the Three Sisters.

Comment: @mcv - The Riverlands were part of the Iron Isles Kingdom, and the Crownlands were constantly being fought over by the neighboring kingdoms. See this answer for a detailed look at the Seven Kingdoms' makeup before the Targaryen conquest:

http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/28004/in-game-of-thrones-which-were-the-seven-kingdoms-of-westeros/28005#28005