# Does anyone actually recognize Cersei as Queen?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In season 6 finale Cersei crowns herself queen of the Seven Kingdoms, but whom will she de facto rule over? Even if we put aside that her realm is about to be attacked by two great forces from the north and the east, there doesn’t seem to be much support for her Iron Throne in the Seven Kingdoms. The North has essentially seceded, as have the Iron Islands, while Highgarden and Dorne are plotting against her. The Vale seems to have aligned them selves with the Starks and while the situation in The Stormlands is currently unknown it is unlikely that they would support a Lannister queen. This leaves only The Westerlands (which were “hers” already), The Riverlands (which might be in disarray after Arya killed the key Freys) and The Crownlands.

I realize that this probably doesn’t even matter in the grand scheme of things with the eminent arrival of the Night’s King and Daenerys, but it just seems that she will not be ruling much, something that she is probably oblivious to in her blind quest for power.

Comment: Relevant: [Can Cersei take Iron Throne and legitimize her act](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/133037/can-cersei-lannister-claim-the-iron-throne-and-legitimize-her-act/133040#133040) 

Also see: [where do regions of Seven Kingdoms appear to be politically aligned in light of Season 6 finale](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/133169/where-do-the-regions-of-westeros-appear-to-align-as-of-the-season-6-finale/133170#133170)

Comment: In any case, this has already been answered by the second question I linked thus making this one a duplicate

Comment: Thank you for the useful comments Aegon. I had looked for similar questions here but failed to find the one you linked to, although they are not really the same since that one focuses on the confrontation between Cersei and Daenerys. However, I realise that this question might not actually be concretely answerable at this time, so I will close it if needed.

Comment: The titles and skimming give that impression but if you take a reading, that question discusses which Regions and houses can possibly accept Cersei's coronation and which regions would rise against it. So it does answer this question I believe.

Comment: Also a duplicate is not a bad thing. A duplicate of a good question means your question is also a good question. It helps others to get to the answers as well.

Comment: From the same Question: North will oppose Cersei, Vale will not accept Cersei but it is unclear whether they will continue alliance with North or not, Iron Islands under Euron will have a choice between Death or Cersei because they can't fight Asha and Daenerys alone, Westerlands are already Cersei's and her powerhub if Jaime doesn't spoil things, Riverlands under Freys will accept cersei to avoid punishment for Red Wedding. If Edmure rises up, he will join with North against Cersei, Reach & Dorne are against Cersei. Crownlands unclear. Stormlands unclear though possibily anti cersei

Comment: Can't be answered.  That was the last scene, literally, of the season. I'd guess that question will be the cause of much strife and conflict next season.